# How do i measure current in 10uA till 10A range in steps of 10uA?

Tags: current, circuit-design, current-measurement

I'm planning to build a circuit that measures the current from uA till 10A DC Line. Initially I thought of using HECT, but it is having better accuracy in higher current range. so I'm figuring  out if i can use the sense resistor to measure lower current(but again burden resistor is trade off here) and HECT for higher current. I need automatic switching here. because the output is fed to DAQ. Suggest me the methodology. I'm also trying in the Internet.
Thanks.

Comment: What accuracy do you want at 10 uA? What accuracy do you want at 10 A?

Comment: At 10uA i can have 2-5% Accuracy . At 10A i need max 1% or less Accuracy is required.

Comment: edit that accuracy information into your question, so it doesn't get lost in the comments. While you're doing that, what speed do you need, and what's the maximum burden voltage you can tolerate? Details like this make the difference between useful and useless answers. You might like to define the acronym HECT for us, when I google it, the first page is full of proteins.

Comment: six decades is a BIG range. Your accuracy specs suggests that you use a log converter.